# Finding previous sibling element with java selenium xpath dynamically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im unsing Selenium to automate some testing.  Im kind of new to selenium. So im trying to validate a form.  Some fields have an asterisk, which denotes a required field.  I'm currently looping through all the visible fields and then checking if the preceding element has a label.  I also need to check if the label has  class of star.  Im not very good with this xpath stuff so any help would be appreciated.

```
for(int index = 0; index < optionOneinputList.size(); index++){
        if(optionOneinputList.get(index).isDisplayed()) {
            optionOneListFinal.add(optionOneinputList.get(index).getAttribute("id"));
            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + optionOneinputList.get(index).getAttribute("id") + "']/preceding-sibling::label")) != null) {
                System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='" + optionOneinputList.get(index).getAttribute("id") + "']/preceding-sibling::label")));
            }

        }
    }
```

and my HTML structure, some of these structures have the star class and some do not.:

```
<div>
    <label></label><div class="star">*</div>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you complete the HTML? The `id` attribute is only present in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for?

```
  "//*[@id='" + optionOneinputList.get(index).getAttribute("id") + 
         "' and preceding-sibling::div[@class = 'star' ]  ]/preceding-sibling::label"
```